# ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter Alternative in Netty 4.0.7

Tags: netty

Hey I noticed that ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter has been removed and i was wonder if there is an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleChannelInboundHandlerAdapter . See also http://netty.io/news/2013/06/18/4-0-0-CR5.html